# Preventing a function from working in JavaScript?! How?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have so far started with a single html page, using individual forms (`<form> </form>`) as the content that is displayed, so clicking onto the submit button will fade out the current form and then fade in the new one. This is done using a downloaded JavaScript demo.

But the thing is that for our assignment we need to use form validation, so when the email and password field is blank it comes up with an alert. So when the submit button is clicked the alert window comes up, but problem is that the form change still happens when it should stay on the current login form?

**This is the login form**

```
<form class="login active" id="logform">
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <div>                         
    <label>Email:</label>                           
    <input id="email3" type="text" />                       
    <span class="error">This is an error</span> 
  </div>

  <div>                     
    <label>
      Password: <a rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a>
    </label>
    <input type="password" id="pass1" />                        
    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">                          
    <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
    <input id="logme" type="submit" onClick="ValidateLog();" rel="emailhome" class="linkform" value="Login"></input>`
    <a rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? Register here</a>                   

    <div class="clear"></div>                       
  </div>                    
</form>
```

**This is the form I'm trying to switch it to**

```
<form id="homeform" class="emailhome">
  <h3>Welcome to CM Email</h3>
  <div>
  </div>
</form>
```

****I just need to figure out a way that stops the form from changing if the validation is incorrect? I've tried using remove attribute class to stop the function from finding the link form, but it still doesnt help!? ****

```
function ValidateLog(){
  //EMAIL VALIDATION
  var emailblank = document.forms["logform"]["email3"].value;  
  if (emailblank==null || emailblank=="")
  {
    alert("Error: Please enter your email.");
    return false;
  }

  //PASS VALIDATION
  var passlog = document.forms["logform"]["pass1"].value;
  if (passlog==null || passlog=="")
  {
    alert("Error: Please enter your password.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/dmr4L/

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `onsubmit` value of the form:

Your validate function then has to return 'false' if the form shall **not** get executed. An example:

```
function myValidateFunction() {
   if (<email is blank>) {
      return false;

   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Another way would be , to replace the submit button:

```
<button onlick="myValidateFunction()" type="button">Submit</button>
```

You would have to change your function to:

```
function myValidateFunction() {
   if (<email is blank>) {
      // do nothing

   } else {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( is there any chance I could send you the files in email please??

Comment: ive got that to work, but instead of going to another url, I want to make it so the form swaps itself with another form. It was using this on the submit button #rel="emailhome" class="linkform"# to call the function that changed it to the emailhome form, is there a way to do this with your method?? sorry to be a pain!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, which would make things a lot easier for you as you're only just starting to learn then you could do the following:

```
<script>
    $('#logform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // will stop redirect

        // now do your validation checks
        if ($('#email3').val() !== '') {
            alert("Error: Please enter your email.");
            return false; 
        } 
        if ($('#pass1').val() !== '') {
            alert("Error: Please enter your password."); 
            return false; 
        }

        // passed validation, do whatever's next...
    });
</script>
```

jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Comment: $('#logform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // will stop redirect

        var emailblank = document.forms["logform"]["email3"].value;  
   
   if (emailblank==null || emailblank=="")
  {
  alert("Error: Please enter your email.");
  return false;
  }

 var passlog = document.forms["logform"]["pass1"].value;
   
   if (passlog==null || passlog=="")
  {
  alert("Error: Please enter your password.");
  return false;
  }// now do your validation checks

        // if validation is good then perform action
        // else show error notificiation
    });

that?

Comment: it doesn't work :( is there any chance I could send you the files in email please??

Comment: did you include jQuery into your document when trying my code?